# Tensorflow for image segmentation: Changing minibatch size stops learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I have created a net for image segmentation, in particular brain tumors. The jupyter notebook with the code is [here](https://github.com/CataRay/tf_Medical-Image-Segmentation/blob/master/3_flair_convnet-deep.ipynb).

When I train the CNN with minibatch size of 1, I get a fairly good result:
[image]

But when I change the size to something larger ( 2 or more) the results are terrible:
[image]

Tensorboard shows the diference in the loss. Clearly the the net with batchsize 2 is not minimizing the loss (blue)
[image]

Any ideas on why this could be the case?

Comment: Is your loss a sum or an average? If the loss is a sum, then the loss would increase linearly with the batch size.

Comment: @ness_boy my loss is: loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output, labels = target)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

Comment: Hmm okay, if you're plotting the `cost` then it should be an average. It's hard to tell what the problem could be without seeing your code though :(

Comment: If you are intrested, the code is here https://github.com/CataRay/tf_Medical-Image-Segmentation/blob/master/3_flair_convnet-deep.ipynb

Comment: Did you try retuning the learning rate? Are you using batch normalization or other things which are sensitive to batch size? It's also possible there's a bug somewhere in your code which is mixing the batch dimension with other dimensions.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I did try multiple learning rates and it did not change. I also rmeoved batch normalization to minimize the possible source odf the error. No luck... Can you elaborate on "mixing the batch dimension with other dimensions" ?

Comment: @CAta.RAy it's very easy in tensorflow to do operations which broadcast in a way that you don't want them to when the dimensions don't match. This can cause information from the labels of different examples in the minibatch to the averaged / erased. You might want to spot check your graph with tfdbg to make sure this isn't the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I checked my graph with tensorboard and I notice that in the CONV1/S1 I was not connecting the output of the ReLu to the next layer (CONV1/S2), instead I was connecting the output of the conv2d directly.

[image]

I changed that line in the code and everything is working as expected.